# B tree insertion

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, branching-and-merging, b-tree

hey i have a questions on my homework and i am being able to solve it i just want someone to  see if i am doing right or wrong...

```
A b-tree with minimum branching factor of t=3

               [D][G][K][N][V]
             /  /  /    |  \   \
            /  /  /     |   \   \
           /  /  /      |    \   \
          AC EF  HI    LM  OPRST  WX

Now when i insert J in above tree this is the output i am getting.... 
                     [K]
                   /      \
                  /        \
                 /          \     
               [D][G]    [N][V]
             /  /  /     /  \   \
            /  /  /     /    \   \
           /  /  /     /      \   \
          AC EF  HIJ  LM    OPRST  WX


After Inserting Q in above tree this is the Final tree i am getting.
                      [K]
                   /      \
                  /        \
                 /          \     
               [D][G]    [N][Q][V]
             /  /  /     /  / \  \
            /  /  /     /  /   \  \
           /  /  /     /  /     \  \
          AC EF  HIJ  LM  OP   RST  WX

  Is this the Final Tree Correct?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the final B tree is not correct. The intermediate one is though. The last one should be  like this

```
                  [K]
               /      \
              /        \
             /          \     
           [D][G]    [N][R][V]
         /  /  /     /  / \  \
        /  /  /     /  /   \  \
       /  /  /     /  /     \  \
      AC EF  HIJ  LM  OPQ   ST  WX
```

You missed something very important. In a B-tree, insertions are only done in the leaf node and every full node on the way is split. You inserted `Q` in a level 2 node in your final tree.

Edit: I think you are confused about the insertion algorithm. Insertions only take place in the leaf node. In the downward path from root to leaf, if any full node is encountered it is split first. If the leaf node is full, it will be split first and then the key will be inserted. In your case the leaf node `OPRST` will be split when it is encountered because it has 5 nodes and is full. Thus `R` will be moved up and and a new leaf node containing keys `ST` will be created. The older leaf node now will only have `OP` keys. `Q` is then compared with `R` and search moves leftward to `OP` node where `Q` finally gets inserted.

Comment: but when we add a node to a already full tree it splits half way so when i inserted a node Q it became OPQRST so 6/2 will be 3 and 3rd node is Q...because b-tree sorts the nodes in correct order too am i wrong?:S

Comment: Yes, because you will never be able to insert Q in the leaf node having `OPRST`. Remember, the minimum degree of your B-tree is 3. Thus the maximum number of keys any node can have is `(2*3-1) = 5`. The node `OPRST` already has 5 keys and hence is full. No way to insert `Q`, without splitting it first.

Comment: ohhkk thankss i got it because i can not pick the middle node from 6 nodes thats why i split first the 5 nodes and R is that node...thanks.. umm i have done one more question in deletion can u look at that too if u can?

Answer (score 0):

If the branching factor is 3, doesn't that mean the minimum number of keys in non-root node? How can the initial tree be correct?

Initial state would be:

```
└── E, I, N, S
    ├── A, C, D
    ├── F, G, H
    ├── K, L, M
    ├── O, P, R
    └── T, V, W, X
```

Comment: I think he means the minimum degree of the B tree is three. In that case, minimum number of nodes in non-leaf nodes would be 2.

Comment: minimum degree of b tree is also said as branching factor where the non leaf nodes can have minimum 2 nodes.